# new operator in function call

Tags: c++, new-operator

My question is what happens to the object allocated with the `new` operator that is inside a function call.

A specific example: I have a private vector `pV` which I want to send to a object/function outside of the class, `foo->func(std::vector<int> *vec)`. I first tried to write

```
foo->func( new std::vector<int>(pV) )
```

but this resulted in a memory leak (when said function is called repeatedly inside a loop). When I specifically created a new object, called the function and then deleted that object, the whole thing worked, without the memory leak.

Shouldn't the newly created object 'expire' and be deleted when the function returns? If not, how should I delete the object, from inside the called function? And which is the better approach?

Comment: In C++, if you use `new`, you need to eventually `delete` that newed data. This is not like Java or C# which use garbage collectors. If you want automatic management, use something like `std::shared_ptr` - but why do you need to make a `new`ed `std::vector`?

Comment: The better approach is to not allocate on the heap unless you need to. Something like `foo.func(pV);` may be all you really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects allocated with `new` must eventually be freed with `delete`, or there will be leaks.  Allocation with `new` is independent of function calls - you can create something with `new` in one function and free it with `delete` in another without problems.

If you want an object that is allocated in a function and freed when the function exits, just do this:

```
void foo(...) {
    // some code

    MyClass myobj(...); // object allocated here
    // some more code
    return; // object freed here (or whenever function exits)
}
```

If you need to pass a *pointer* to your object to a function, you needn't use `new` for that either; you can use the `&` operator:

```
std::vector<int> myvec(pV);
foo->func(&myvec);
```

In this case `myobj` is an automatic variable which is placed on the stack and automatically deleted when the function exits.  There is no need to use `new` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think yours is the best answer to my question. To add to it - the new `pV` will exist only in the called function "space" and can (should) be `deleted` inside it. And upon further revision of my code I learned that I can call the function without the `new` operator.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as new objects "expiring" in C++: it is not a garbage collected or reference counted language, so you are expected to manually code all memory management of objects that you allocated with `new` or `new[]`.

In this particular case, you could use `unique_ptr` to ensure automated deletion:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10000 ; i++) {
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int> > tmp = new std::vector<int>(pV);
    foo->func(tmp);
}
```

There is no magic here, even though it does not look like there is a `delete`: the call to `delete` is coded explicitly inside `unique_ptr`, so for all practical purposes it's still manual.

A better solution would be to allocate your vector in the automatic storage, and pass a pointer to `foo->func`:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10000 ; i++) {
    std::vector<int> tmp(pV);
    foo->func(&tmp);
}
```

Comment: @Mat Point taken - replaced `auto_ptr` with `unique_ptr`, and explained where the magic deletion happens.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is neither.
Simply pass `pV` itself. It will get copied (by the copy constructor) so a new vector will be created anyway. It will be automatically destroyed upon function return.